# Can't see my created file

Tags: android

Somebody told me that when i will create my file i will be able to see it in sdcard/android/data/myproject name/files
By i am not seeing my created file
I am using this code...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.savedata);

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.proceed);

    EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {

        public void onClick(View arg)

        {

            File f=new File(getFilesDir(),"Save.txt");

            try{

            f.createNewFile();

            }

            catch(Exception exc)
            {}

        }

    });

}
```

Please help me i am new to android development

Comment: add check code to check if f.exist() in your code.. but this method stores it in your internal memory so check internal memory not external

Comment: also at least print stack trace from the exception ....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg) {
        try {
            File newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestFolder");
            if (!newFolder.exists()) {
                newFolder.mkdir();
            }
            try {
                File file = new File(newFolder, "MyTest" + ".txt");
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("ex: " + ex);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("e: " + e);
        }
    }
});
```

and also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I want to store my file in custom location without using getFilesDir() .. is it possible if yes then please can you send me a short code it will be helpful indeed..

Answer (score 0):

Well, many things may happen here.

- Your directory may be locked by mounting storage or something simillar
- Maybe you can't save in this directory because it does not exists
- Android can block this directory for your app (4.4 and its permissions to save)
- You dont set permissions in manifest
- And many more

And you don't check any of this. In your code method createNewFile() returns boolean after save, so you know if its complete or not. Also exception can be thrown right away if something bad happens (no dir? There is createDirs(). Blocked dir - get other location from Environment). Check that and you will know what is going on.